# got error when using javascript ajax json to retrieve php array

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

My html page is suppose to retrieve the array from the php page and alert the first element in the array. But when I run the html, got the following error, "Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'parseJSON' " in the console window. I tried to use jQuery.parseJSON(json_data)    instead of  $.parseJSON(json_data) but still got the same error. How can I fix this?

script.js:

```
function getArr(){                      
alert('return sent');           
$.ajax({              
url: "n1.php",             
 type: "GET",             
 success: function(json_data){                  
 var data_array =jQuery.parseJSON(json_data);                 
 var rec = data_array[0];                   
 alert(rec);                    
 alert("GOOD");              
 },               
 error: function() {                  
 alert("BAD");               
  }          });                     
 }
```

newcal.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="demo.css">


<body onload="getArr();">
<div id="rounded"><div id="main" class="container">
<div id="pageContent"> 
Hello, this is the default content
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script     type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

n1.php:

```
<?php

$output = array("cat","dog");
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: Is it normal that your head-Tag closes after your body-Tag? ;-)

Comment: oops, didnt see that, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseJSON` was added in jQuery 1.4.1 (in 2010)

You are using jQuery 1.3.2 (from 2009), which is too old.

The current version of jQuery 1.x is 1.11 (released this year).

Use a more recent version of jQuery.

---

You should also tell the browser that you are sending it JSON instead of claiming that your JSON is HTML. (PHP defaults to claiming that anything it outputs through a web server is HTML)

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
$output = array("cat","dog");
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Then let jQuery parse it automatically:

```
success: function(data_array){                  
    // Remove the following line. It will be parsed automatically.
    // var data_array =jQuery.parseJSON(json_data);                 
    var rec = data_array[0];
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much!!!!!!!! Does header("Content-type: application/json"); mean that the return type of php is always JSON?

Comment: It means that the HTTP response header will inform the client (e.g. the browser) that the HTTP response body consists of JSON.

Comment: function(data_array) does not parse element by element, it's char by char , so the response is ["cat", "dog"] and data_array[0]="[", not "cat", do u know how i can fix that? thx!!